# How to fix Angular 7 Router Guard not working

Tags: angular

I am trying to write a router guard that checks if page terms have been accepted, if not, deny access.

Here is the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ItemService {
  public _itemsSource = new Subject<any | null>();
  itemsObservable = this._itemsSource.asObservable();


  constructor(
    public afs: AngularFirestore
  ) {
  }

  getItemSettings(){
   return  this.itemsObservable.pipe(
      first(),
      switchMap(item => {
       return this.afs.doc(`table-items/${item.id}`).valueChanges();
      })
    );

  }
```

and here is the guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class ItemEditGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private itemService: ItemService, private router: Router,  private notify: NotifyService) {}
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
      return this.itemService.getItemSettings().pipe(
        take(1),
        map((settings: any) =>  !!settings.terms),
        tap(acceptedTerms => {
          if (!acceptedTerms) {
            this.notify.update('<strong>Access Denied!</strong> You need to accept to collection terms to continue!', 'error');
            return;
          }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

The routermodule

```
 {
      path: 'edit',
      component: ItemEditComponent,
      canActivate: [ItemEditGuard],
      data: { title: 'Edit item', breadcrumb: 'EDIT' },
}
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working with no errors logged.
Btw, it's on a lazy loaded module.
What am I doing wrong? and how can I fix this?

Comment: StackBlitz Example will help more!

Answer (score 0):

1_ **`tap()`** operator used to perform some action to received value before subscription is made, and **`map`** for manipulate, transform it.

2_ as you said you're trying to use this guard in **`lazyloaded`** module, so a **`canLoad`** interface need to be implemented and not **`canActive`**

`@Injectable()
export class ItemEditGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private itemService: ItemService,
        private router: Router,
        private notify: NotifyService
    ) { }
    canActivate(
        route: Route,
        segments: UrlSegment[]
    ): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
        return this.itemService.getItemSettings()
            .pipe(
                map((settings: any) => !!settings.terms),
                map(acceptedTerms => {
                    if (!acceptedTerms) {
                        this.notify.update('<strong>Access Denied!</strong> You need to accept to collection terms to continue!', 'error');
                    }
                    return acceptedTerms;
                })
            );
    }
}`

you can read more about :

- > [can load](https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad)
- > [first() vs take(1)](https://swalsh.org/blog/rxjs-first-vs-take1)
- > [map()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html)
- > [tap()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html)